# 3d perspective effect only working correctly in chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hello i am having some difficulties achieving the same 3d perspective effect in other browsers. Everything works and displays correctly in Chrome. Here you will see a true 3D perspective effect on mouse movement. But in firefox, everything looks flat and is not the correct effect.

Is there a trick to getting this to work correctly on all modern browsers?

Tagging Jquery also because open to a Jquery solution.

## What it looks like in chrome:

[image]

## What it looks like in Firefox:

[image]

How can I achieve the same effect on all modern browsers?

```js
!(function ($doc, $win) {
 var screenWidth = $win.screen.width / 2,
  screenHeight = $win.screen.height / 2,
  $elems = $doc.getElementsByClassName("elem"),
  validPropertyPrefix = '',
  otherProperty = 'perspective(1000px)',
  elemStyle = $elems[0].style;

 if(typeof elemStyle.webkitTransform == 'string') {
  validPropertyPrefix = 'webkitTransform';
 } else if (typeof elemStyle.MozTransform == 'string') {
  validPropertyPrefix = 'MozTransform';
 }

 $doc.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
  var centroX = e.clientX - screenWidth,
   centroY = screenHeight - (e.clientY + 13),
   degX = centroX * 0.02,
   degY = centroY * 0.01,
   $elem

  for (var i = 0; i < $elems.length; i++) {
      $elem = $elems[i];
   $elem.style[validPropertyPrefix] = otherProperty + 'rotateY('+ degX +'deg)  rotateX('+ degY +'deg)';
  };
 });
})(document, window);
```

```css
html, body{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}


body {
  background: #004382;
  overflow: hidden;
}
 .desk-scene{
  height: 100%;
  background-size: contain;
  max-width: 982px;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:nowrap;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.threed {
  height: 100%;
  background-size: contain;
  max-width: 982px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.desk-scene-wrapper{
  height: 100%;
  background-size: contain;
  width: 100%; display:block;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.desk-scene-wrapper1{
  width: 100%;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  z-index: 9999;

}
.desk1 {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width:982px;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
 background: url('http://portalpacific.net/img/desk/ian-xing.png') no-repeat center center;
  background-size: contain;
  position:absolute;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(180px) scale(1);
  z-index: 1;
}
.wrapper {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width:982px;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
 background: url('http://portalpacific.net/img/desk/cloud.png') no-repeat center center;
  background-size: contain;
}

.bloc {
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
  background: url('http://portalpacific.net/img/desk/icon-circles.png') no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  max-width:982px;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position:relative;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-self:center;
  background-size: contain;

}

.content {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(80px) scale(1);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 720px;
  position: absolute;
  margin:auto;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 3;
}

.content1 {
 transform: translateZ(80px) scale(1);
 background: url('http://portalpacific.net/img/desk/Website.png') no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  max-width:982px;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position:relative;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-self:center;
  background-size: contain;
}

.content2 {
    background: url('http://portalpacific.net/img/desk/webicons.png') no-repeat;
  transform: translateZ(30px) scale(1);
  background-position: center;
  max-width:982px;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position:absolute;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-self:center;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="threed">
    <div class="desk-scene-wrapper1">
        <div class="desk1"> </div>
    </div>

    <div class="desk-scene-wrapper">

        <div class="desk-scene">

            <div class="wrapper elem" style="transform: perspective(700px) rotateY(0deg) rotateX(0deg);">

                <div class="bloc">

                    <div class="content content1">
                    </div>

                    <div class="content content2">
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I'm shifting the elements based on the mouse position: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VGXBee (not as nice as the native Chrome version though)

Comment: Thats pretty cool. This might work.. I am playing with your settings but having a hard time dialing down the amount of movement. Like im trying to make the icons not go too far out of the darker circle squares behind them.

Comment: increase the divisors (updated the codepen, also fixed the center coordinate calculation)

Comment: Post this as an answer. This will work as a solution. I appreciate the help!

Comment: Post as answer please.

Answer (score 0):

Given that other browsers seem to handle 3D transformations differently, one could move the center to fake the effect:

```js
!(function($doc, $win) {
  var screenWidth = $win.innerWidth / 2,
    screenHeight = $win.innerHeight / 2,
    $elems = $doc.getElementsByClassName("elem"),
    otherProperty = "perspective(500px)",
    elemStyle = $elems[0].style;

  $doc.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
    var centroX = e.clientX - screenWidth,
      centroY = screenHeight - (e.clientY + 13),
      degX = centroX * 0.02,
      degY = centroY * 0.01,
      $elem;

    for (var i = 0; i < $elems.length; i++) {
      $elem = $elems[i];
      $elem.style.transform =
        otherProperty + "rotateY(" + degX + "deg)  rotateX(" + degY + "deg)";
    }
    $doc.getElementsByClassName("content1")[0].style.left = (centroX / 25) + "px"    
    $doc.getElementsByClassName("content1")[0].style.top = -(centroY / 25) + "px"    
    $doc.getElementsByClassName("content2")[0].style.left = (centroX / 50) + "px"
    $doc.getElementsByClassName("content2")[0].style.top = -(centroY / 50) + "px"
  });
})(document, window);
```

```css
html, body{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}


body {
  background: #004382;
  overflow: hidden;
}
 .desk-scene{
  height: 100%;
  background-size: contain;
  max-width: 982px;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:nowrap;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.threed {
  height: 100%;
  background-size: contain;
  max-width: 982px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.desk-scene-wrapper{
  height: 100%;
  background-size: contain;
  width: 100%; display:block;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.desk-scene-wrapper1{
  width: 100%;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  z-index: 9999;

}
.desk1 {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width:982px;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
 background: url('http://portalpacific.net/img/desk/ian-xing.png') no-repeat center center;
  background-size: contain;
  position:absolute;
  transform: translateZ(180px) scale(1);
  z-index: 1;
}
.wrapper {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width:982px;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
 background: url('http://portalpacific.net/img/desk/cloud.png') no-repeat center center;
  background-size: contain;
}

.bloc {
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
  background: url('http://portalpacific.net/img/desk/icon-circles.png') no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  max-width:982px;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position:relative;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-self:center;
  background-size: contain;

}

.content {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 720px;
  position: absolute;
  margin:auto;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 3;
}

.content1 {
 background: url('http://portalpacific.net/img/desk/Website.png') no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  max-width:982px;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position:relative;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-self:center;
  background-size: contain;
}

.content2 {
    background: url('http://portalpacific.net/img/desk/webicons.png') no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  max-width:982px;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position:absolute;
  display:flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-self:center;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="threed">
    <div class="desk-scene-wrapper1">
        <div class="desk1"> </div>
    </div>

    <div class="desk-scene-wrapper">

        <div class="desk-scene">

            <div class="wrapper elem" style="transform: perspective(2000px) rotateY(0deg) rotateX(0deg);">

                <div class="bloc">

                    <div class="content content2"></div>
                    <div class="content content1"></div>

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The crucial part is:

```
$doc.getElementsByClassName("content1")[0].style.left = (centroX / 25) + "px"    
$doc.getElementsByClassName("content1")[0].style.top = -(centroY / 25) + "px"    
$doc.getElementsByClassName("content2")[0].style.left = (centroX / 50) + "px"
$doc.getElementsByClassName("content2")[0].style.top = -(centroY / 50) + "px"
```